# How to check if same value is present in consecutive locations in a circular array?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

There is circular array. How do I check if same values are present in consecutive locations? That is, for an array of length 5, array[4] and array[0] are consecutive locations.

Comment: What have you got so far? Did you have any particular language in mind?

Comment: I have implemented this array as an arraylist in Java. The only way I have found so far is using additional arrays for each value that will be stored in this array (no. of different values this array can hold is predefined, also the count of these values is known). This array will hold the index of these values from the parent array.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the [tag:java] tag to your question as well as some minimal code showing how you declare and use the array, but the general idea will be to index the ArrayList using `index % array.size()`.

Comment: Suppose the values this array can hold are  2 Ws, 2 Bs and 2 *s. If the array is in any of the following states, the function should return a success
W W * B B * ||
W * B B * W ||
* B B * W W ||
B B * W W * ||
B * W W * B ||
* W W * B B *

Answer (score 0):

go around the arrayList and store the current int in a dummy variable.  As you iterate compare against each one and replace.  Repeat until the entire way around.

```
dummy = inf
currentInt = arrayList[0]
for(int = 0; int < size; int++){
    if(dummy == currentInt){return there is a repeat}
    dummy=currentInt
    currentInt=nextInt
}return no repeat
```

Comment: i did not clearly understand it, could you possibly explain that in a bit more detail, please?

Comment: @phaedrusH something like that.